# Multiple error when trying to push to remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-remote, repo

after coding up a javascript project, I wrote

```
git push -u origin main
```

however it gives me back:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Undefined error: 0
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[pic to describe it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmxEW.jpg)

What should I do?  Im new to git/github in general and have been trying to solve it with out luck.  Thank you to all the answers in advance

Comment: These are the instructions for SSH. Have you uploaded an SSH key to GitHub? https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: yes thank you it worked!

Comment: Have you add the *remote-url* from the git repository? Before `git push`, add the url with `git remote add origin https://github.com/user-name/repo-name.git`.

Comment: Side note: that error message, `Undefined error: 0` is terrible. Apparently the Mac version of ssh needs a bit of work. (Which macOS are you running?)

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to GitHub via SSH, ensure that you have uploaded an SSH key to GitHub. This article explains the process.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 1):

The issue does not seem to be the same as the OP, but the symptoms are very similar, and I'm sharing the solution to my issue. I.e `git` operations like fetching failed with

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Undefined error: 0
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

At the time I was on macOs Sonoma (14.1), on my phone's **personal hotspot**.

Debugging the connection didn't help much

```bash
$ ssh -vT git@ssh.github.com
OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/ME/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/ME/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/ME/.ssh/config line 26: Deprecated option "useroaming"
debug1: /Users/ME/.ssh/config line 29: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/tmp/ssh_mux_ssh.github.com_22_git" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Undefined error: 0
```

My ssh config is configured to "multiplex ssh connection via `ControlMaster`, so if there's no control socket it should create one, and it just fails too.

When going back to my regular wifi hotspot, the ssh command worked flawlessly. The ssh command only failed when connected to my phone's personal hotspot.

Also, I found out that SSH connection was failing on any host when on my personal hotspot. Yet it was possible to establish a TCP connection on the host (via netcat), e.g. `ssh.github.com` on port `22`.

```bash
$ nc -w 1 "140.82.121.35" 22
SSH-2.0-babeld-f8b1fc6c
```

And after "bisecting" the `~/.ssh/config` I found the key `AddressFamily inet` was the cause. I'm not sure why it was an issue since there's an `A` record for `ssh.github.com`.

So the fix was, either

```
  Host *
-   AddressFamily inet
```

Or

```
  Host *
-   AddressFamily inet
+   AddressFamily any
```

---

Note the `UseRoaming` settings had no incidence in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this ssh issue is still present on MacOS 14.3.1 & iOS 17.3.1.

Removing `AddressFamily inet` from `~/.ssh/config` also solved it